# Check if images in DIV are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it were possible to check if all the images within a div are loaded before running executing?

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="check()">
    <div id="testdiv">
        <img id="test" src="assets/image.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function check() {
    var test = document.getElementById("testdiv").complete;
    alert(test);
}
```

It returns "undefined".

Comment: .complete is used for ajax calls not for the image loading as far as i know

Comment: By "executing" do you mean "before running script"?

Comment: you can use the `onload` on `img` tag that image is loaded or not.

Comment: @KawineshSK - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp it is for image completetion.

Comment: @SumanBogati - I am aware of that, but the div will have over 100 images in it, I want to have it say `images are loading...` then once all loaded to change to displaying the images, for this I need to check every single one separately OR check if the div is "loaded"

Comment: @user3256987 do you know how many images are exactly there?

Comment: @SumanBogati 117, but more will be added as the site gets older.

Comment: basically you want to execute particular code after 117 images are loaded am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether all the images has been loaded properly, you can wrap your code inside `$(window).load(function() {....});`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

or you can also try this:

```
var $images = $('div#testdiv img');
var loaded_images_total = 0;

$images.load(function(){
    loaded_images_total ++;

    if (loaded_images_total == $images.length) {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks pretty promising, I tested your second example - doesn't seem to work correctly (no error messages, no alert) :s

Comment: Check out the docs for using jQuery's .load() to bind to the load event of an image. Make sure you read the section titled `"Caveats of the load event when used with images"`.

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the load event.

#### » [Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/tzhQP/) «

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").load(function(e) {
        console.log("OK", e);
    })
    .error(function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
    });
})
```

Where we attach, as by example from OP, to `load` on `<img>` tag.

```
<div id="testdiv">
    <img id="test" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-300-200-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! This seems to be working! I'll do some tests and get back to you.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` does not wait for images, only for scripts and styles to be loaded and DOM elements to be rendered according to their relevant styles. If you want to wait for all images to be loaded before executing a block of code, you must use `$(window).load()`.

Comment: @AlexKinnee - but he is checking for an ID to be loaded?? or is he tricking me? :O

Comment: @AlexKinnee: That's why we further go for `load` on **image** element.

Comment: @AlexKinnee I just tested - he's/her answer seems so far correct. I just have to give the images an ID and then it'll check if they are loaded or not. `Pretty close to what I asked for`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread this answer. Using .load() on an ID which references an image element WILL work in most cases.

Comment: @user13500 - would it be possible to limit the image loading `with ID/without` to a div? I've tested and it still alerts even if the images aren't in a certain div?

Comment: @user3256987: If I read you correctly, yes. You *should* go for the img element and not the div.

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(d) {    
        alert(d.id+":: Loaded" );
    }
</script>


<img id="test" src="assets/image.jpg" onload="check(this)"/>
```

Comment: This is the only solution other than mine that is actually somewhat deterministic.  The others will all fail, because adding event listeners for an event that may have already happened is just bugs waiting to happen.  You'll want to an an onerror case though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ES6 function, `awaitImgs()`, that you can use to perform a task after all `<img>` elements in the specified container element have resolved (i.e., have loaded or failed to load).

Basic usage:

```
awaitImgs(someContainerElement).then(complete).catch(failed);
```

Comments welcome.

```html
<html>
<head><title>Image Load Test</title></head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  <img src=""/>
  <img src="some_image.png"/>
  <img src="some_other_image.jpg"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
   * Returns a promise that is fulfilled when ALL <img> elements in the specified container element
   * have either loaded, failed to load, or never attempted to load due to an empty or missing src
   * attribute.
   */
  let awaitImgs = (elem) => {
    console.log('=================BEGIN WAITING FOR IMGS===============');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let imgs = Array.from(elem.querySelectorAll('img'));
      let numImgs = imgs.length;
      let numImgsResolved = 0;
      let numImgsFailed = 0;

      let handleImgLoaded = (img) => {
        console.log('Complete: ' + img.src);
        numImgsResolved++;
        checkForDone();
      };
      let handleImgFailed = (img) => {
        console.log('Failed: ' + img.src);
        numImgsResolved++;
        numImgsFailed++;
        checkForDone();
      };
      let checkForDone = () => {
        if (numImgsResolved === numImgs) {
          // All images have either loaded or failed, so fulfil the Promise
          resolve(numImgsFailed);
        }
      };

      console.log(`Waiting for ${imgs.length} images...`);
      // Examine each image to determine whether it is already complete. If an given image isn't
      // already complete, wait for its onload or onerror events to be dispatched.
      imgs.forEach((img) => {
        console.log(`src: ${img.getAttribute('src')}, complete: ${img.complete}, naturalWidth: ${img.naturalWidth}`);

        let imgIsEmpty = !img.hasAttribute('src') || img.getAttribute('src') === '';
        if (imgIsEmpty) {
          // This img element has no src attribute OR src is set to the empty string. This is an
          // edge case that should be avoided. We treat such img elements as resolved.
          handleImgLoaded(img);
        } else if (img.complete) {
          // This image has finished loading
          if (img.naturalWidth > 0) {
            // We treat complete images with greater-than-zero width as valid and resolved
            handleImgLoaded(img);
          } else {
            // We treat complete images with 0 width as invalid, but resolved
            handleImgFailed(img);
          }
        } else {
          // This image hasn't finished loading yet, so handle load and
          // error cases with event listeners
          let loadListener = (e) => {
            e.target.removeEventListener('load', loadListener);
            handleImgLoaded(e.target);
          };
          img.addEventListener('load', loadListener);

          let errorListener = (e) => {
            e.target.removeEventListener('error', errorListener);
            handleImgFailed(e.target);
          };
          img.addEventListener('error', errorListener);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  // Example usage:
  let div = document.querySelector('#content');
  let complete = (numFailed) => {
    console.log(`All images resolved. Number of images that failed to load: ${numFailed}`);
    // Work to perform after all images have loaded goes here
  };
  let failed = (result) => {
    // Safety net that executes if an exception is thrown inside awaitImgs()
    console.log(`Error: ${result}`);
  };

  awaitImgs(div).then(complete).catch(failed);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When `div` has no images, this function seems to get stuck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // everything on the page has loaded.
});
```

That will fire once things load.  However, it won't tell you if a particular div has loaded all of its assets, nor will it tell you if you have broken images.

If you want to do a check for a particular div, this is harder.  You can't really check to see if images are loaded after HTML parse, because the HTML engine can load them before you script gets a chance to add a listener.  So, you need to add listeners directly to each image as it gets added, which means you've got to be the one to do it.

There isn't a 'sugar' way of doing this, which leaves you with something like this:

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
<script>
// load directly in the page.  Not necessary, but simpler to talk about.

var imageCounter=0, images = ['foo/bar.jpg','foo/bar2.jpg', .... ];

function checkCounter(){
    imageCounter++;
    if (imageCounter >=images.length)
    {
       // load completed.  Do some stuff.
    }
};
for (var ii=0; ii< images.length; ii++)
{
    var pImg = $('<img>')
         .on('load',function(){imageCounter++; checkCounter();})
         .on('error', function(){imageCounter++;checkCounter();});
    pImg.attr('src', images[ii]);
    pImg.appendTo('#dynamic');
}
</script>
```